# How to output a symmetric hollow matrix using Deep Learning Model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, point

I'm working on a project that requires to output a symmetric hollow matrix where diagonal element are all zero using deep learning model. Any reference on related research? or Code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever you want to output a matrix `A` (e.g. an MLP or whatever DL architecture makes sense for your problem), and then just make it symmetric and hollow by defining

```
sym_hollow(A) := (A + A.T) - 2*diag(A)
```